# This is bibliography code is not compiling why?

Tags: bibliographies

```
\begin{thebibliography}{6}
\bibitem{3} C Kabele, {\em Transistos},  Journal of the American Society for Naval Engineers, {\bf 65}, 707--714, 1953.
\bibitem{2} J M Early, {\em Out to Murray Hill to Play: An Early History of Transistors},  IEEE Transactions on Electron Device, {\bf 48}, 2001.
\bibitem{4} R Nelson, {\em The Link Between Science and Invention: The Case of the Transistor}, The Rate and Direction of Inventive Activity: Economic and Social Factors, 549--584, 1962.
\bibitem{1} S Soni and V Dagolia, {\em The Transistor Amplifier}, International Journal of Electrical & Communication Engineering for Applied Research, {\bf 1}, 1--20, 2012.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the special character `&` (using `\&`) in the last `\bibitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{6}

\bibitem{3} C Kabele, {\em Transistos}, Journal of the American Society for Naval Engineers, {\bfseries 65}, 707--714, 1953.

\bibitem{2} J M Early, {\em Out to Murray Hill to Play: An Early History of Transistors}, IEEE Transactions on Electron Device, {\bfseries 48}, 2001.

\bibitem{4} R Nelson, {\em The Link Between Science and Invention: The Case of the Transistor}, The Rate and Direction of Inventive Activity: Economic and Social Factors, 549--584, 1962.

\bibitem{1} S Soni and V Dagolia, {\em The Transistor Amplifier}, International Journal of Electrical \& Communication Engineering for Applied Research, {\bfseries 1}, 1--20, 2012.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not related, but `\bf` is an obsolete command; you should use `\bfseries` instead.

Comment: tried it didn't work :S

Comment: @Raed simply saying "didn't work" is useless. If you try my example code as it is, you'll see no errors are produced and the result is the expected. If something is not working for you, exactly what it is? Do you get any errors/warnigs? If so, which ones?

Comment: @Raed so if finally worked? If so, and you consider my answer solved your proble, please consider marking it as accepted (by clicking the checkmark to its left). In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).